# Import data from the excel file

Tags: c#, import-from-excel, oledbdatareader

In the below mentioned code, data is imported from an Excel file containing `Sent_date` column in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Each data row is iterated upon and `sent_date` and *date values* stored in the `ex_date` variable.

```
      protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlTransaction transaction;

        string ex_id = "";
        var count = 0;



        string file_name = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        string Excel_path = Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + file_name);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Excel_path);

        using (OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel_path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False"))
        {
            my_con.Open();

            // get the excel file data and assign it in OleDbcoomad object(o_cmd)
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", my_con))
            {

                // read the excel file data and assing it o_dr object
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                { 

                    /////////////////////////////////////////////
                   // while (dr.Read() && count++ < 10)
                   while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        //get first row data and assign it ex_id variable 
                        ex_id = dr[0].ToString();
                        string ex_uid = dr[1].ToString();
                        //get second row data and assign it ex_name variable
                        string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();
                        //get thirdt row data and assign it ex_name variable

                        string ex_dir = dr[3].ToString();

                        //get first row data and assign it ex_location variable
                        string ex_email = dr[4].ToString();
                        string ex_email1 = dr[5].ToString();
                        string ex_email2 = dr[6].ToString();
                        //string ex_company = dr[7].ToString();
                        string ex_company = dr[7].ToString();
                        string ex_contact = dr[8].ToString();
                        string ex_proposal = dr[9].ToString();
                        string ex_reason = dr[10].ToString();
                        //string ex_type = dr[11].ToString();

                        int chk = 0;
                        int type = 0;
                        int dup = 0;
                        int dir = 0;

                        if (ddlwebsites.SelectedIndex != 0)
                        {
                            dir = Convert.ToInt32(ddlwebsites.SelectedValue);
                            if (dir == 8)
                            {
                                type = 1;
                            }

                        }


                        foreach (ListItem lstAssign in ddlevents.Items)
                        {
                            if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
                            {
                                chk = 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (type == 1 && chk == 0)
                        {
                            evyerror.Text = "Please Select the Event!!";
                            return;

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            string querycomp = "", compID = "";
                            querycomp = "Select * from barter_company where website like '%' '" + ex_dir + "' '%'";
                            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarterConnectionString"].ToString();
                            connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                            connect.Open();
                            transaction = connect.BeginTransaction();
                            try
                            {
                                ClassDtBaseConnect clsDtResult = new ClassDtBaseConnect();
                                DataTable dt = clsDtResult.GetDataTable(querycomp);
                                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    compID = dt.Rows[0]["comp_id"].ToString();
                                    ViewState["comp_id"] = compID;
                                    if (type == 1)
                                    {
                                        dup = checkforDuplicates(Convert.ToInt32(compID));
                                        if (dup == 1)
                                        {
                                            //Confirm_MP.Show();
                                            // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "confirmation();", true);
                                        }

                                    }
                                    //return;
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    string queryStr = "insert into barter_company (comp_name,website) values(?comp,?website)";
                                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, connect, transaction);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comp", ex_company);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?website", ex_dir);
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    cmd.CommandText = "Select LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                                    compID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                                    transaction.Commit();
                                    connect.Close();

                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                            }





                            if (dup == 0)
                            {
                                // create a connection string with your sql database 
                                string connStr1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarterConnectionString"].ToString();
                                connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr1);
                                connect.Open();

                                DateTime date = new DateTime();//added by chetan
                                ex_date = ex_date.Split(' ')[0];//added by chetan
                                date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);//added by chetan
                                string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");//added by chetan
                                DateTime SentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(SentDateString).Date;//added by chetan
                                                                                            //DateTime SentDate = DateTime.Parse(ex_date);//added by chetan


                                // }
                                //date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//added by chetan
                                //date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
                                // string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                                transaction = connect.BeginTransaction();
                                try
                                {

                                    ex_uid = Session["session_barterUser_id"].ToString();


                                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into barter_proposals(user_id, sent_date, website_a, email_id, email_id2, email_id3, company, contact_name, proposal_status, reason,type) values(?uid,?sentdate,?dir,?email,?email2,?email3,?comp,?cont_name,?pro_status,?reason,?type)", connect);

                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?uid", ex_uid);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comp", compID);

                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sentdate", SentDate);
                                    // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?event", eventname);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?dir", dir);
                                    // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?bar_type", ddlbartertype.SelectedValue);
                                    // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?website_b", txtwebsite.Text);
                                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comp", ex_company);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cont_name", ex_contact);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", ex_email);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email2", ex_email1);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email3", ex_email2);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pro_status", ex_proposal);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?reason", ex_reason);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?type", type);
                                    // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?type", type);

                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    if (type == 1)
                                    {

                                        cmd.CommandText = "Select LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                                        Int64 CurrentProId = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                                        int eventAssignID;
                                        string QueryInqEventAssign = "insert into barter_propeventassign(prop_id,event_id) values(?pro_id,?event_id)";

                                        foreach (ListItem lstAssign in ddlevents.Items)
                                        {
                                            if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
                                            {
                                                cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryInqEventAssign, connect, transaction);
                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pro_id", CurrentProId);
                                                eventAssignID = Convert.ToInt32(lstAssign.Value);
                                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?event_id", eventAssignID);
                                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                            }
                                        }

                                    }//end of if
                                    transaction.Commit();
                                    connect.Close();
                                    Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Proposal Added Successfully!!!');</script>");
                                }//end of try
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    transaction.Rollback();
                                    Response.Write("<script>alert('There is an Error Ocurred:" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>");
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    connect.Close();

                                }

                            }//ifdupzero
                        }//else
                    }//while   


            //dr.Close();//commented by chetan
        }//using
    }//using

  }//using

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Excel_path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Excel_path);
        }


    }
```

Now the issue is that suppose when an excel file contains 3 rows as given below:

```
sent_date
11/21/2017----1strow
11/22/2017----2ndrow
11/23/2017----3rdrow
```

The `Reader` does read the 3 rows but but does not stop after that. It again goes to while loop and reads the date (actual value:"") and gives the error `"string is not recognised as datetime"`.

A strange thing observed is that while importing *16 rows* it does not give this error - the reader stops and data gets inserted. No idea why it takes 16 rows to stop the `reader`

What should be added to the code to stop the reader after reading the initial 3 rows - that is after reading 3rd row, how will it go to `dr.close()`?

Comment: the whole point of `using` is that it cleans up the connection. don't call `Close` on it explicitly. Oh and use proper C# naming conventions

Comment: How to stop after 3 rows? `var count = 0; while (dr.Read() && count++ < 3) {}`

Comment: what if there are 10 rows?Actually,it should import according to number of rows there in a excel file...

Comment: It depends on what your data looks like. If you have a standard format, you can figure it out. Otherwise, you can either test the value and conditionally parse it using `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact` or catch the exception and `return` from the enclosing method.

Comment: var count = 0; while (dr.Read() && count++ < 9) {}.....So here,if there are 12 rows in a excel file,it will take only 9 rows from the excel file....right?

Comment: Right, I didn't know your requirements. Is the only way you can stop encountering invalid data?

Comment: Is it possible that if reader checks whether the row contains data or not in a excel file...if 1strow contains data then it can enter inside while loop and do the execution...if 2nd row is empty,the reader should get closed...

Comment: The reader is always automatically closed because of the `using` statement. You should remove your close statements they don't make any sense. The point of the using statement is that it cleans up resources like connections regardless of how you exit the block. Even if an exception is thrown cleanup is guaranteed. That's the purpose of the construct

Comment: Also that was what I said in my first comment, why aren't you reading?

Comment: I have removed dr.close() and mycon.close()......Exactly @AluanHaddad...the reader should be automatically closed after importing data from the excel file..but in my case,suppose if there are 7 rows that i wanted to import from excel,so after importing 7 rows,it is not getting closed...it again go into the while loop for the 8th time and read the date(actual value:"")...

Comment: you're going around in circles. It's not about closing the reader it's about exiting the loop. That's the problem you have to solve.

Comment: var count = 0; while (dr.Read() && count++ < 9) ....this is for setting the limit i.e.user can import only 9 rows......while(dr.Read())..this is for to import as many rows from excel file...For limit purpose,var count = 0; while (dr.Read() && count++ < 9) is working great i.e. i can import only 9 rows out of n rows....But for while(dr.Read())...suppose if there are 7 rows that i wanted to import from excel,so after importing 7 rows,it is not getting closed....

Comment: it is always closed that isn't the problem. The problem is you get an exception and your program terminates. The reader is still closed. There are so many ways you could solve this problem. You need to go back to basics. Examine the fundamental logical requirements

Comment: I have just added my actual code...kindly check and just let me know if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: yes something is very wrong. You cannot maintain that code. You have all your code in one method that's like 200 line don't do that. Variable mutation everywhere every which way. If you understand the code now you won't when you look at it in a month.

Comment: Heck even mixed up writing a response stream via HTTP in with the database logic. How do you expect anyone to maintain that code?

Comment: And to make it worse that stream is serializing HTML that contains embedded JavaScript for a valuation on the client. You have at least four programming languages in one giant function and three of those languages are sitting in strings the whole thing needs to be scrapped throw it out and start over

Comment: everything is working superb...data is getting inserted into the database...only the problem is while loop...

Comment: that code is not acceptable. You say it's working perfectly except for the loop but there's a giant loop around so many different concerns. Please consider studying basic procedural programming decomposition. Nothing fancy mind you, just how to have multiple methods that do different things and then compose them.

Answer (score 0):

While reading excel file, you need to consider concept of empty/used rows. If you delete rows from excel after 3 rows and import it again, the issue won't arise.

As per your explanation, excel is having total 16 used rows but data is populated only in 3 rows.

To come out while loop after 3 data rows, you will need to enter more exhaustive where condition like "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [F1] <> ''"